# Can i install Python-unicodecsv in Python 3.0?

Tags: python-3.x, server, ubuntu-12.04, vps, odoo-8

Im trying to install python-unicodecsv in python 3.0 for Odoo. but it say "unable to locate package python-unicodecsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the download in below from the git repository

**https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv**

Installation steps:

**Step 1. Download and Extract the .zip file**

download directly as zip file and extract it from the below way

**Extract within the same directory :**

```
unzip python-unicodecsv-master.zip <your .zip file name>
```

**Extract within the another directory :**

```
unzip python-unicodecsv-master.zip <your .zip file name> -d <direcroty path>
```

**Step 2. Install the .zip file using terminal in Ubuntu**

just go to the extracted directory path through the terminal then type the below command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

then finally your library installed successfully and you can 
access the all the library which are related to the python-unicodecsv and used it in your python file.

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Comment: You can always just [`pip install` from github](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2crput/how_to_install_with_pip_directly_from_github/). And thats only 1 single step